# Play Wistia video in full screen with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wistia

I have a wistia video hidden by default and a custom play button that makes the video appear. When that button is clicked, I not only want the video to appear and start playing, but I want it to go directly into full screen mode. Looking through their JavaScript API, I don't see an option to put it in full screen mode. All I see is an option to allow it to be in full screen. Is there a way to accomplish this, or does the user have to actually click the full screen button in the video player for this to happen?

Answer (score 3):

You can just seek for video tag after wistia video is set up to playback mode. In their docs no another solution for this.
Take a look:

```js
// get wistia video object through their api
var wistiaVideo = Wistia.api('your video id');

$('#your-custom-play-button').on('click', function() {
  wistiaVideo.play();

  // now just look for video tag inside wistia video container
  var video = $('.your-video-container').find('video')[0];

  // check whether your browser has ability to run it in fullscreen mode
  if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (video.webkitEnterFullscreen) {
    video.webkitEnterFullscreen();
  }
});
```